# Python: calculate the weighted average correlation coefficient

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, numpy, pearsons-correlation-coefficient

I am calculating the volatility (standard deviation) of returns of a portfolio of assets using the variance-covariance approach. Correlation coefficients and asset volatilities have been estimated from historical returns.

Now what I'd like to do is compute the **average** correlation coefficient, that is the common correlation coefficient between all asset pairs that gives me the same overall portfolio volatility.

I could of course take an iterative approach, but was wondering if there was something simpler / out of the box approach in numpy or pandas?

I've tried googling, but can't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn can calculated weighted correlation

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).